# Wiener Lemma for matrix valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, wiener-algebra

The ordinary Wiener lemma states that if $f(x):=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n \exp(inx)$ ($\sum |a_n|<\infty$) and if $f(x)\neq 0$ everywhere, then $g:=1/f$ can also be written as
$$g(x)= \sum b_n \exp(inx)$$
with $\sum_n |b_n|<\infty$
The proof of this uses the fact, that an element $u$ of a commutative Banach Algebra is invertible iff $h(u)\neq 0$ for each complex homomorphism.

Now, I have seen a similar result used in a paper - more specifically: substitute square- matrices in place of the coefficients $a_n$, i.e. consider functions of the form
$$f(x):= \sum A_n \exp(inx)$$
Assume now that each $f(x)$ is an invertible matrix. Does it then follow (and if so, why) that $f^{-1}(x)$ can be expressed as
$$f^{-1}(x):= \sum B_n \exp(inx)$$
for some matrices satisfying $\sum |B_n|<\infty $
I don't know how to proceed here, because in this case the Banach Algebra is not commutative. Can I still adapt the proof of the original Wiener Lemma somehow?

Comment: I think that this question is suitable for MathOverflow. It might be better to wait some more days before posting it there. Do not forget to refer to the present question.

Comment: A reference: Wiener's Lemma holds for coefficients from an arbitrary unital Banach algebra, see Cass, Trautner: An extension of Wiener's lemma to Banach algebra valued functions, Arch. Math. 40 (1983), 260-265.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the [Adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) satisfies the following relation: $$\forall A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R),\; A \text{ adj}(A)=det(A)Id.$$
And the Adjugate matrix is defined using the determinat function, so we need to understand how it acts on $f(x)$.

**Lemma:** Let $f(x)=\sum A_n e^{inx}$ with $A_n\in M_k(\mathbb k)$ hence exists $\alpha_n\in \mathbb k$ such that $det(f(x))=\sum \alpha_n e^{inx}$.

**proof:** By the [cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) we know that for given $g_j(x)=\sum b^{(j)}_n e^{inx}$, with $j=1,\ldots,N$ exists $b_n$ s.t. $\prod_{j=1}^Ng_j(x)=\sum b_n e^{inx}$. Now by definition of [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):
$$det(f(x))=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)f(x)_{1,\sigma(1)}f(x)_{2,\sigma(2)}\cdot\ldots\cdot f(x)_{k,\sigma(k)}=$$ $$=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)[\sum_n (A_n)_{1,\sigma(1)}e^{inx}]\cdot\ldots\cdot [\sum_n (A_n)_{k,\sigma(k)}e^{inx}]=$$ $$=\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\sum_n \alpha_n^{\sigma} e^{inx}=\sum_n(\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\alpha_n^{\sigma})e^{inx}=\sum_n\alpha_ne^{inx}. \;\;\square$$
Now by the Wiener lemma, since $det(f(x))\neq 0 \;\forall x$, there exist $\beta_n\in \mathbb k$ s.t. $det(f(x))^{-1}=\sum \beta_n e^{inx}$.

So now we have only to  work on the adjugate matrix, especially if we show that the $f(x)$'s cofactor matrix  is of the form $\sum_n B_n e^{inx}$ we are done, because:
$$f(x)^{-1}=det(f(x))^{-1}\text{ adj}(f(x))=\left[\sum \beta_n e^{inx}\right]\left[\sum_n B_n e^{inx}\right]^t=$$ $$=\left[\sum_m \beta_m e^{imx}\right]\left[\sum_n B_n^t e^{inx}\right]=*$$
This is a scalar multiplication and if we apply the cauchy product to every matrix's component we get:
$$*=\sum_n C_n e^{inx},\;\;\text{ with } C_n=\sum_k B_{n-k}^t\beta_k.  $$

**cofactor matrix study:** Let $C(x)$ be the $f(x)$'s cofactor matrix, by definition $C(x)=((-1)^{a+b}M_{ab}(x))$ where $M_{ab}(x)$ is determinant of the $(k-1)\times(k-1)$ matrix that results from deleting row $a$ and column $b$ of $f(x)$ (it's still of the form $\sum A_n'e^{inx}$). For the lemma we know that exist $\alpha_n^{(a,b)}\in\mathbb k$ s.t.
$\;M_{ab}(x)=\sum \alpha_n^{(a,b)}e^{inx}$, hence:
$$C(x)=\sum C_n e^{inx},\; \text{ with } (C_n)_{ab}=(-1)^{a+b}\alpha_n^{(a,b)}. $$
So for the previous argument we can conclude.

Comment: *missing the part about the convergence of $\sum |B_n|$.